# mysqldump slow alter table issue

Tags: mysqldump

I notice mysqldump always put the command ALTER after INSERT.

```
CREATE TABLE ...;
INSERT table ....;
ALTER TABLE ...;
```

Is it possible to change the sequence to ALTER table first?

```
CREATE TABLE ...;
ALTER TABLE ...;
INSERT table ....;
```

When restoring data, this is needed as ALTER could be very slow with large tables with many records. Sometimes it could take more than 10 minutes to ALTER table.

Comment: What alters are that? There is usually a reason to do them after data import - foreign keys are added after other tables are imported because otherwise it might break, indexes may be added after data because that way the total time of insert+alter is significantly less than what inserts into a table with indexes would take etc.

Comment: In some cases, it is faster to build an index _after_ all the data is present, rather than _building on the fly_.